# Make Flask update a rendered HTML page every hour?

Tags: python, flask

I am implementing a web scraping site and rendering the HTML using Flask.

How do I set it up so it runs and updates the rendered web page, say every hour?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
"# Last bit of the code is here which works well otherwise

    print(df)

    @app.route('/')
    @app.route('/corona')
    def corona():
        return render_template('corona.html',  tables=[df.to_html(classes='female')], titles=df.columns.values)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(debug=True)"
```

Comment: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask

Comment: Celery is what you're looking for

Comment: Couldnt figure it out can u please help